# Data summary based on multiple categorical variables

Tags: r, summary

I'm trying to create a summary based on a data that contains the following columns:

```
    Trx_Date   Brand   Cust_Num   Item_Qty   Item_Price
```

I am trying to create a summary of the Item_Qty and Item_Amt based each week of the year for different Brand (a character object class). I have managed to create Wk_Num by:

```
    Wk_Num <- as.character(strftime(as.POSIXlt(Trx_Date), format="%W"))
```

What I am trying to do is to get the sum of the Item_Qty and the mean of the Item_Price for each Wk_Num+Brand combination. I manage to get what I want through the following:

```
   tblsum <- summary(Item_Price + Item_Qty ~ Wk_Num + Brand, data=tblorig, FUN = function(x) { c(m = mean(x), s= sum(x))})
```

What I want to do is to create another column which calculates the percentage of the buyers of all the total buyers (i.e. penetration) for each particular Wk_Num+Brand combination. I can revise the code above to calculate the length as well (to get the number of "buyers" for each combination), i.e.

```
   tblsum <- summary(Item_Price + Item_Qty ~ Wk_Num + Brand, data=tblorig, FUN = function(x) { c(m = mean(x), s= sum(x), l=length(x))})
```

However, this is flawed as well, as customers may actually purchase multiple times within a week and they will be double counted.

I'm still way early in my **R** journey and trying to code it elegantly. Is there a good way of combining the data summary that I build from the first code as well as calculate the % of unique Cust_Num for each Wk_Num+Brand combination over the total number of unique Cust_Num?

Any improvement of the code would be greatly appreciated as well.

**Update:**

Sample data:

```
 Wk_Num   Brand      Cust_Num   Item_Qty   Item_Price
 11       AAA           001          1          2.1
 11       BBB           001          1          1.4
 11       AAA           002          2          2.1
 12       CCC           003          1          1.5
 12       BBB           001          3          1.4
 12       BBB           001          2          1.4
 12       BBB           004          1          1.5
 12       CCC           004          1          1.5
 13       AAA           002          2          2.2
 13       AAA           001          3          2.1
 13       AAA           003          1          2.2
 13       AAA           004          2          2.1
```

What would be ideal as the output is:

```
 Wk_Num   Brand     Total Item  Avg Item Price   Penetration
 11       AAA             3        2.10              50%         # 2 out of 4
 11       BBB             1        1.40              25%         # 1 out of 4
 12       BBB             6        1.43              50%         # 2 out of 4 (Cust 001 bought twice in that week)
 12       CCC             1        1.50              25%         # 1 out of 4
 13       AAA             8        2.15             100%         # 4 out of 4
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `ddply` function from the `plyr` package:

(Assuming the data frame is called `dat`.)

```
library(plyr)
ddply(dat, .(Wk_Num, Brand), summarise, 
      Total_Item = sum(Item_Qty), 
      Avg_Item_Price = mean(Item_Price),
      Penetration = length(unique(Cust_Num))/length(unique(dat$Cust_Num)))
```

The result:

```
  Wk_Num Brand Total_Item Avg_Item_Price Penetration
1     11   AAA          3       2.100000        0.50
2     11   BBB          1       1.400000        0.25
3     12   BBB          6       1.433333        0.50
4     12   CCC          2       1.500000        0.50
5     13   AAA          8       2.150000        1.00
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `data.table`:

```
require(data.table)
x.dt <- data.table(dat)
yy <- x.dt[, list(Total_Item = sum(Item_Qty), Avg_Item_Price = mean(Item_Price),
            Penetration = length(unique(Cust_Num))/length(unique(x.dt$Cust_Num))), 
            by="Wk_Num,Brand"]
```

Comment: +1 Could store the result of `unique(x.dt$Cust_Num)` first for speed rather than calculate the same number each time for each group since `unique` is relatively expensive.